# Why to use non complex algorithms

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In my Intro to AI class, we have been studying:

- Uniformed Search (i.e. Depth-First Search)
- Informed Search (i.e. A* Search)
- Constraint Satisfaction pRoblems (i.e. Hill Climbing)
- Adversarial Search (i.e. Minimax)

In general lines, why would we use, for example, Depth-First Search instead of using more complex algorithms such as A* Search? In other words, why choosing simple and limited algorithms when we can choose complex ones?

Comment: The algorithms in your example have different properties. DFS has worst case O(n) memory constraints, whereas A* has worst case O(2^n). A better comparison would be BFS vs A*

Comment: Efficency could matter in most cases. In some particular cases (e.g. a game so simple that it has only a few branching trees, or a combinatorial problem with only 50 cases) it does not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is efficiency. Some algorithms take much more time/memory than others. 
Some algorithms won't work will in certain situations. For example, if there are local maxima, Hill Climbing won't work very well.
If you expect most paths to lead to destination, you can use Depth First, which could be much faster than A*.